# Has anyone implemented a GWT JSNI wrapper over jsbn.js?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am looking for code wrapping the Javascript BigInteger jsbn.js module for use in GWT. Does anyone have some to share? I could not find any on Google. Thanks.

Comment: After searching the web extensively, it does not seem like such code is available online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably to use the GWT-Math library: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-math/

It includes implementations of java.math.BigDecimal and java.math.BigInteger.